# data.map is not a function (it is undefined)

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I'm making a recipe app with React Native and Firebase. I added some JSON data to realtime database before. It works well with arr.map(). But when I write a data to realtime database with my project it says data.map is not a function

Here is the code that i made my calls from realtime database

```
import { ScrollView, SafeAreaView, FlatList } from "react-native";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { ref, onValue } from "firebase/database";
import { database } from "../firebaseConfig";
import HomepageCard from "../components/HomepageCard";

export default function AllRecipes() {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  function getData() {
    const db = database;
    const recipes = ref(db, "tarifler/");
    onValue(recipes, (snapshot) => {
      setData(snapshot.val());
    });
    setIsLoading(false);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{ alignItems: "center" }}>
data.map((recipe) => {
              const { ad, id, gorsel, kategori } = recipe;
              return (
                <HomepageCard
                  key={id}
                  ad={ad}
                  gorsel={gorsel}
                  kategori={kategori}
                />
              );
            }) </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

Here is my write data to realtime database component

```
import { View, Text, Pressable, Alert } from "react-native";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { ScrollView, TextInput } from "react-native-gesture-handler";
import { ref, set } from "firebase/database";
import { database } from "../firebaseConfig";
import "react-native-get-random-values";
import { nanoid } from "nanoid";

export default function AddRecipe() {
  const id = nanoid();
  const [data, setData] = useState({
    ad: "",
    gorsel: "",
    kategori: "",
    tarif: "",
    malzemeler: "",
  });
  const handleOnPress = () => {
    const db = database;
    set(ref(db, "tarifler/" + id), {
      id: id,
      ad: data.ad,
      kategori: data.kategori,
      gorsel: data.gorsel,
      yapılış: data.tarif,
      malzemeler: data.malzemeler.split(","),
    });
    
  };
  return (
    <ScrollView style={{ flex: 1 }} className="bg-white gap-y-6 px-5 pt-10">
      <Text className="text-2xl font-bold">Add Recipe</Text>
      <View className="gap-y-5">
        <TextInput
          onChangeText={(val) => (data.ad = val)}
          className="text-xl p-4 bg-[#F6F6F6] rounded-xl"
          placeholder="Ad"
        />
        <TextInput
          onChangeText={(val) => (data.gorsel = val)}
          className="text-xl p-4 bg-[#F6F6F6] rounded-xl"
          placeholder="Görsel Linki"
        />
        <TextInput
          onChangeText={(val) => (data.kategori = val)}
          className="text-xl p-4 bg-[#F6F6F6] rounded-xl"
          placeholder="Kategori"
        />
        <TextInput
          onChangeText={(val) => (data.tarif = val)}
          multiline={true}
          numberOfLines={6}
          className="text-xl h-[200px] p-4 bg-[#F6F6F6] rounded-xl"
          placeholder="Tarif"
        />
        <TextInput
          onChangeText={(val) => (data.malzemeler = val)}
          multiline={true}
          numberOfLines={6}
          className="text-xl h-[200px] p-4 bg-[#F6F6F6] rounded-xl"
          placeholder="Malzemeler"
        />
      </View>
      <Pressable onPress={handleOnPress} className="bg-pink-600 rounded-full">
        <Text className="text-center text-xl font-medium text-white py-3">
          Tarifi Ekle
        </Text>
      </Pressable>
    </ScrollView>
  );
}
```

When I removed the new added data from realtime database its work properly again

Comment: Your only use of `data.map` in the code you provided is commented out and shown out of context, so we can't really see exactly what the problem is.  What are you expecting `data` to be if not undefined?

Comment: sorry i edited it

Comment: Why do you expect `snapshot.val()` to give you an array or other object with a `map` method?

Comment: Doesnt it give me an object?

Comment: @carrie yes, it gives you an object. Objects don't have the `map` method

Comment: @Konrad i fixed the issue but im thinking i declared useState variable as an array but why its changes the type of variable after fetching and pushing some data. Doesn't it make any sense to declare the type of useState variable?

Comment: JavaScript is dynamically typed. You set the initial value to `[]` but then you change it to an object. You can't declare a type in javascript

Answer (score 0):

From how the code looks currently, I would expect you to call `setData()` with some array value, but you call it with the output of `snapshot.val()` (which is probably an object). Objecs don't have the `.map()` method on them (hence your error). Check what `snapshot.val()` returns you and if it's the right object structure do something like `setData([...data, snapshot.val())`.

Comment: its giving me an object. but the main problem is when I delete the new added database item my code is works.

Comment: Please provide a bit more context. It works when you 'delete the new added database item' ? So it allows you to add a new item but somehow once the new element added, it does not work anymore and when you delete the new item it works? If it lets you add a new item (although you definitely need to push it in that setter function or set it with  the spread operator like so `[...data, newItem]`. Please provide a bit more context so I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check the code below

```
setData(snapshot.val());
```

Verify that snapshot.val() returns an array and not an object, objects do not have the Map function

Answer (score 0):

Try optional chaining:

```
data?.map?.(...)
```